# how to debug macro?

Tags: c, debugging, macros

having this code:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define check(x) ({int _val = (x); (_val ==-1? \
    ({fprintf(stderr, "Error (" __FILE__ ":%d) -- " \
    "%s\n",__LINE__,strerror(errno)); \
    exit(-1);-1;}) : _val); })

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc!=2){
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }

    int fd;
    fd=open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);

    if(fd<0){
        perror("open");
        fprintf(stderr,"errno = %s\n",strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
    }

    for(char c;check(read(fd,&c,1))>0;) //macro "check(x)" HERE
        fputc(c,stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles without an error, but I can see the macro does not output error messeges (`__FILE__`, neither `__LINE__`), as define it the macro. How to fix that? (And for general, how to debug macro, how at least output some error for it)?

`$cc -pedantic a.c`

```
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:10:2: warning: ISO C forbids braced-groups within expressions [-Wpedantic]
  ({fprintf(stderr, "Error (" __FILE__ ":%d) -- " \
  ^
a.c:30:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘check’
  for(char c;check(read(fd,&c,1))>0;)
             ^~~~~
a.c:9:18: warning: ISO C forbids braced-groups within expressions [-Wpedantic]
 #define check(x) ({int _val = (x); (_val ==-1? \
                  ^
a.c:30:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘check’
  for(char c;check(read(fd,&c,1))>0;)
```

*not single mention* about `for loop` (only its location, because the macro is in there, but that is not error) statment. Only about macro. So please focus on macro problem and not about the for loop.

EDIT1:
the macro actually comes from this guy:
[youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZiUT-ipnj0) (at the end of the video), well he uses clang, so I do not know what clang uses as a preprocessor (and therefor it works for him).

EDIT2 (output from a.i - preprocessed output):

```
# 304 "/usr/include/fcntl.h" 3 4

# 8 "a.c" 2







# 14 "a.c"
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
```

I have deleted all the noise. But you can see between `#include <fcntl.h>` and `int main`, there is nothing. But there should be the `#define check(x)...`. So it does not tell me WHY is it missing.

Comment: You can't use a block of statements as an expression inside a `for()` loop header.

Comment: You also can't put `()` around a block of statements.

Comment: I'm surprised this even compiles.

Comment: @Barmar huh? Why cannot I? If I cannot, then there would be error from compiler, the second argument of `for` is just condition and since macro `check` returns either `-1` or `0`, it will be evaluated.

Comment: Did you try looking at the pre-processed version of your code? Compilers support outputting that separatly. It is usually easier to find the problem from point of view of compiler than from point of view of pre-processor. Because the latters ways are more twisted...

Comment: @Barmar I am not asking about corretness of the `for loop` since there is no problem. The problem is in macro in the string "Error ..., as title of the question suggest

Comment: @Herdsman Why? Because the C standard says so. :)

Comment: Aside: the use of an identifier with a leading underscore like `_val` is reserved.

Comment: @klutt so I am going to ignore the fact, compiler gave no error? :)

Comment: Statement expressions are a GNU extension. Adding `--pedantic` I got warnings.

Comment: @Barmar, you are right - only about macro :), I have editted post

Comment: @Herdsman Did not read the whole question first. Just jumped into the conversation. My bad. But what Barmar said, it's an extention.

Comment: No obvious reason for `check()` to be a macro - why not use a function?

Comment: @barny It needs to be a macro so it can get `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` from the place where the error occurred, not the function body.

Comment: @barny I do not not whether function does have `__LINE__` or `__FILE__` which is handy is the error message

Comment: Well, to be fair you aren’t actually getting those, are you?Run it in a debugger and you’ll see the stack trace

Comment: Make it a macro which passes `(x),__FILE__,__LINE__` as parameters to `check(x,filename,lineo)`

Comment: But for how to debug it. I would start by emptying your main function. Start with just `int main() { check(-1); }` and increase complexity gradually.

Comment: Use both. Write a function *and* a macro that invokes it. The function takes the result of `(x)` , `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` as arguments,  dumps those args when reporting errors, and returns the same result passed in . That would also be completely portable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how to debug macro?

#### Read more about C, in particular the [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) book then [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) site.

Most C compilers have a way to show the preprocessed form of a [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit).

#### Read the documentation of your C compiler.

For [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), see [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/). For [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/), see [that](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html). The GCC preprocessor is documented [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/).

If you use `gcc` as your C compiler on file `foo.c` **run [it as](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html#Invoking-GCC) `gcc -C -E -H -Wall foo.c > foo.i` to obtain into `foo.i` the preprocessed form of `foo.c`** (but most comments are kept, and you could add more of them). Then **look with a [pager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_pager) or an editor** (I recommend [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), but feel free to use [vim](https://vim.org/), [gedit](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/), `more`, `less`, `most` etc...) **into that generated `foo.i`  file**.

> I can see the macro does not output error messeges

**A macro is not outputting any messages, it is just expanded.**

If you use a [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool such as [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/), read its documentation.

If you use some [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), read its documentation. Many IDEs offer a way to show the preprocessed form, and some might even make the macro expansion on the fly.

Don't forget that in *some* cases, **you may want to use some *other* preprocessor**, such as [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) or [GNU m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/), or **generate some C code programmatically** (like [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/), or [lemon](https://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/), or [SWIG](https://swig.org/) does). Many [transpilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler) (such as [Chicken-Scheme](https://www.call-cc.org/) or [Bigloo](https://www-sop.inria.fr/mimosa/fp/Bigloo/bigloo.html#License)) are [generating C code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065), and in [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) I am doing that at run time, then dynamically loading the generated plugin, using [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html). In [RefPerSys](https://refpersys.org/) we want to generate C++ code at runtime, and later use [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/).

You can find lots of [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) [C preprocessors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor), even standalone ones like [mcpp](http://mcpp.sourceforge.net/). You could study their source code and improve them for your needs. And [tinycc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler) or [nwcc](http://nwcc.sourceforge.net/) is a small enough open source C compiler (with their preprocessor embedded inside) that you could improve in a few days.

If you use a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), you could extend it with your own [plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html), perhaps adding your own `_Pragma` (used in your macros) which would display things after preprocessing.

Some clever debuggers (e.g. a suitably configured recent [GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/)) are capable of macro expansion (thrn compile your C code with `gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall`)

In [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/), I use lots of quite long C macros. They might be inspirational. And so is the [container-macros](https://github.com/clsr/container-macros) library. And also [GTK](https://gtk.org/) whose macros are very readable.

My experience: **to debug a macro, remove many lines from it, till you are satisfied with its expansion.** Grow that macro in small steps. Use [git](https://git-scm.com/) on your source code.

> ```
> $cc -pedantic a.c
> ```

I recommend using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g3 -H -pedantic a.c` on Linux then use a recent `gdb`.

Comment: Yes, thanks, look at my edit. The precompilled output shows nothing (missing the definition of the macro), but I cannot reproduce why. Anyway I use vim as editor not emacs, so I hope I will not make enemies today :D

Comment: @herdsman in the precompiled output you won't have the definition of the macro, but you should fond it "exploded" where it is issued.

Comment: @Herdsman it was preprocessed so it does not exists anymore. Compiler does not deal with macros.

Comment: @basile _"run it as gcc -C -E -Wall foo.c > foo.i to obtain into foo.i "_ even better: you can generate foo2.c, compile it with the debug symbols and debug it.

Comment: @basile : It could be a little offtopic, but I have seen `bison` in a lot of gnu binutils, can you tell me in short what it does and its purpose? (because in real life I have never used it). Just short explanation would be enought. Thanks

Comment: No, GNU bison has an excellent documentation and tutorials. Please **read them**; since I will do much worse

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking you can't debug a macro as macro is not something which is executed.

> But there should be the #define check(x).... So it does not tell me
>   WHY is it missing.

Your macro was preprocessed - ie textually replaced by the preprocessor.

After the preprocessing it is expanded to:

```
    for(char c;({int _val = (read(fd,&c,1)); (_val ==-1? ({fprintf(
              stderr
              , "Error (" "./example.c" ":%d) -- " "%s\n",30,strerror(
              (*__errno_location ())
              )); exit(-1);-1;}) : _val); })>0;)
        fputc(c,
               stdout
                     );
```

Comment: Yea, I forgot the how the preprocessed output should look like. Anyway, why does it work for that guy from tutorial, and not for me. That sucks :(

Answer (score 1):

You can't debug a macro in the sense that a high level debugger will step through the macro code. What you can do is temporarily expand the macro in the source code and use a debugger to see what is going wrong.

One idea is to use a code formatter, like clang-format to beautify the macro so that you can understand it better an use the debugger. Applying this idea, transform the macro into a function and let the formatter do its job:

```
$ clang-format -i macro.c
```

results in:

```
void check1(x) {
  ({
    int _val = (x);
    (_val == -1 ? ({
      fprintf(stderr,
              "Error (" __FILE__ ":%d) -- "
              "%s\n",
              __LINE__, strerror(errno));
      exit(-1);
      -1;
    })
                : _val);
  })
}
```

The code you originally posted actually compiles and executes properly here. I made a version with a few cuts to be able to test the macro:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define check(x) ({int _val = (x); (_val ==-1? \
    ({fprintf(stderr, "Error (" __FILE__ ":%d) -- " \
    "%s\n",__LINE__,strerror(errno)); \
    exit(-1);-1;}) : _val); })

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    check(-1);
    return 0;
}
```

results in:

```
$ gcc a.c && ./a.out
Error (a.c:13) -- Success
```

Comment: The program you posted, when applied to a text file, just prints it. The macro needs the function `read()` to fail in order to place an error message. I just simulated the error using `-1` as the macro argument.

Comment: `$./a.out non_exist_file` should give something like `Error (a.c:13) -- blabla`, but it does not. It will fail by getting non-existing file and then trying to `read` it, but no ouput like that.

Comment: No, if the file does not exist, `open()` fails and the macro code is never reached.

    $ gcc a.c && ./a.out asdfsadf
    open: No such file or directory
    errno = No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little late, but I wanted to say that you didn't place a check where you want the code to be checked (opening the file).

Change this:

```
fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
```

To this:

```
check(fd=open(argv[1], O_RDONLY));
```

That's what Jacob is doing in its video. He is additionally adding the check in the read operation, but that's completely secondary and aimed to catch errors that came after the file was opened successfully (No example of this kind of errors was shown in the video).